# Tensorflow Custom Metric: SensitivityAtSpecificity

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

## Background

The metric for my machine learning task is `weight TPR = 0.4 * TPR1 + 0.3 * TPR2 + 0.3 * TPR3`. Generally, it asks for a model with higher recall rate while disturbing less negative samples.

Some terminology:

> - TPR（True Positive Rate, Sensitivity) : TPR = TP /（TP + FN）
> - FPR（False Positive Rate, 1 - Specificity）: FPR = FP /（FP + TN）
> - TP、FN、FP、TN stands for True Positive, False Negative, Fasle Positive and True Negative.
> - TPR1：TPR at FPR = 0.001
> - TPR2：TPR at FPR = 0.005
> - TPR3：TPR at FPR = 0.01

## My attempt

Since keras does not have such metric, we need to write our own custome metric. Another word for mention, unlike in lightgbm and xgboost, custom metric in `keras` is not straight-foward because training process are on tensors instead of pandas/numpy arrays.

In lightgbm/Xgboost, I have this `wtpr` custom metric, and it works fine:

```
def tpr_weight_funtion(y_true,y_predict):
    d = pd.DataFrame()
    d['prob'] = list(y_predict)
    d['y'] = list(y_true)
    d = d.sort_values(['prob'], ascending=[0])
    y = d.y
    PosAll = pd.Series(y).value_counts()[1]
    NegAll = pd.Series(y).value_counts()[0]
    pCumsum = d['y'].cumsum()
    nCumsum = np.arange(len(y)) - pCumsum + 1
    pCumsumPer = pCumsum / PosAll
    nCumsumPer = nCumsum / NegAll
    TR1 = pCumsumPer[abs(nCumsumPer-0.001).idxmin()]
    TR2 = pCumsumPer[abs(nCumsumPer-0.005).idxmin()]
    TR3 = pCumsumPer[abs(nCumsumPer-0.01).idxmin()]
    return 0.4 * TR1 + 0.3 * TR2 + 0.3 * TR3
```

In keras, I write a custom metric below. It works with regular tensor input, but it failed during **model fitting with batch Gradient descent**:

```
import keras.backend as K
def keras_wtpr_metric(y_true, y_predict):
    n = y_predict.shape[0]
    
    a = tf.dtypes.cast(y_predict, tf.float32)
    b = tf.dtypes.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    a = tf.reshape(a,shape = [-1])
    b = tf.reshape(b,shape = [-1])
    d = tf.stack([a,b], axis = 0)
    d = tf.gather(d, tf.argsort(a,direction='DESCENDING'), axis = 1)
    PosAll = tf.math.reduce_sum(b, axis = -1) # the number of positive samples
    NegAll = tf.math.reduce_sum(1-b, axis = -1) # the number of negative samples
    pCumsum = tf.math.cumsum(d[1]) # TP
    pCumsum = tf.dtypes.cast(pCumsum,dtype = tf.float32)
    nCumsum = tf.range(0,n,dtype = tf.float32) - pCumsum + 1 # FP
    pCumsumPer = pCumsum / PosAll # tpr
    nCumsumPer = nCumsum / NegAll # fpr
    TR1 = pCumsumPer[tf.math.argmin(abs(nCumsumPer-0.001))]
    TR2 = pCumsumPer[tf.math.argmin(abs(nCumsumPer-0.005))]
    TR3 = pCumsumPer[tf.math.argmin(abs(nCumsumPer-0.01))]
    return tf.reduce_sum(0.4*TR1+0.3*TR2+0.3*TR3)
```

My model is :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(load_breast_cancer().data, load_breast_cancer().target,test_size = 0.3)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
# I have a tabular data
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],)), 
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = [keras_wtpr_metric])
# it seems can not work under batch training, I don't know why
model.fit(x=x_train, y= y_train, batch_size = 2048, epochs = 30,validation_data = [x_test,y_test])
```

Error message is

```
Epoch 1/30
398/398 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/sample
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-639-da481d44d615> in <module>
      5 ])
      6 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = [keras_wtpr_metric])
----> 7 model.fit(x=x_train, y= y_train, batch_size = 2048, epochs = 30,validation_data = [x_test,y_test]) # it seems can not work under batch training, I don't know why

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [0] vs. [398]
     [[node metrics/keras_wtpr_metric/sub_1 (defined at /Users/travis/opt/anaconda3/envs/envpython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_681042]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

## My question

1. How to write a weighted SensitivityAtSpecificity in keras?
2. Why my `keras_wtpr_metric` failed?

## Some Useful Sources:

1. https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics
2. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SensitivityAtSpecificity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `n = tf.shape(y_predict)[0]` intead of `n = y_predict.shape[0]` for dynamically take into account the batch dimensionality

pass also your validation data in round brackets: `validation_data = (x_test,y_test)`

here the running notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uUb3nAk8CAsLYDJXGraNt1_sYYRYVihX?usp=sharing

Comment: It works! However, I cannot tell why these two orders(tf.shape function and tensor's shape method ) are different.

Comment: tf.shape and Tensor.shape should be identical in eager mode. Within tf.function or within a compat.v1 context, not all dimensions may be known until execution time. Hence when defining custom layers and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic tf.shape(x) over the static x.shape